# Getting a 404 Error from GetStaticPaths NextJs

Tags: javascript, axios, next.js, custom-error-pages

Next JS dynamic routes show a 404 Error.
Tried doing it dynamically 1st for debugging tried doing it manually. http://localhost:3001/question/62e7b69ca560b1c81aa1a853. This is the route. Tried using fallback true and false. Tried online solutions didn't work.

pages -> question -> [id] -> index.js

```
export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  try {
    return {
      paths: [
        {
          params: {
            id: '62e7b69ca560b1c81aa1a853',
          },
        },
      ],
      fallback: true,
    };
  } catch (err) {
    return {
      paths: [],
      fallback: false,
    };
  }
};

export const getStaticProps = async ({ params }) => {
  const res = await axios.get(
    `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/q_a/getQAquestionById/${params.id}`
  );
  const data = await res.data.data.question;
  return {
    props: {
      question: data,
    },
    revalidate: 1,
  };
};
```

Comment: Can you show us your `pages` folder structure?

Answer (score 0):

Fallback as 'true' shows the fallback version of the page. You can update the fallback to 'blocking' which will fetch the data and render the page and store it so that the next fetch retrieves the cached version of the page.